Memory leakage in python?
I have python scripts that calls a function foo that performs some operations that uses say 10GB of memory and returns the small object res to the main program. After printing res I delete the res, but top shows the ipython process is sill using about 1GB of memory. How can I ensure the process frees up all unused memory?
def foo():
   .... # some complication operation
   return res

if __name__ == "__main__":
    res = foo()
    print(res) 
    del res
    


I tried using gc.collect() but the it does not change anything.
I have read that sometimes the memory becomes fragmented and python can not reclaim all the memory.

Can you show us a more accurate representation of your script? Right now, del res is effectively a no-op, as it will be cleaned up on script exit anyways, which is the next step in this script

del doesn't delete objects, it deletes names. If there are any other references to the object, it won't get garbage collected. There is not enough information here to do anything but wildly speculate. Note, shells like IPython tend to keep references to objects that you allowed to be printed by the REPL

not sure if this would help but try del the other variables within foo(). You might also want to look at pythons garbage collection module.

@RahulMehta that will definitely not help, they are all effectively deled when the function returns

Does this answer your question? How can I explicitly free memory in Python?

The memory isn't wasted. Most likely a handful of small objects produced in the process of performing your work survive (e.g. free lists held internally in types like tuple, objects held in I/O cache, small objects created by IPython's background threads, etc.), and as a result, the large blocks the allocator requests from the OS can't be returned, because at least one living object is still inside them.
This isn't really an issue though. If the program needs memory later on, the already allocated space will be reused (cheaply) before it asks for any more from the OS (more expensive). And if the memory is never used again, and other processes actually need it, the memory will be paged out (or even dropped without paging out if the OS provides memory hinting facilities that the allocator uses, though CPython does not do that at present) due to lack of use, and the physical RAM will be used by another process that actually needs it.
This problem is not specific to Python (low-level C programs using malloc can see the exact same issue, whether they implement their heap as a contiguous sbrk-based heap or use custom allocators to make a non-contiguous heap of mmap-segments the way Python's allocator does). There's no magic way to have an allocator that handles small objects completely avoid fragmentation and return all unused memory to the OS deterministically and completely.
Stop worrying about it. Memory is cheap, your program hasn't leaked anything (probably; weird C extensions can get things wrong and leak stuff, but I'm assuming you don't have any hand-written C extensions involved here), it's just not able to return all of it to the OS. This is normal, in every program, in every programming language (object-relocating GC as performed by stuff like the Java Runtime can reduce fragmentation to minimize this problem, but is has other costs that simpler approaches like those used by C's malloc and CPython's allocator don't pay, and in practice, the reduced fragmentation doesn't do a lot to get memory back to the OS anyway, so you'd see the same behaviors).

Good answer thanks. The fact that  memory can reused by the process later on is reassuring.

Note that gc.collect() may not necessarily free up all unused memory, but it can help reclaim memory that is no longer in use.
Python's memory management system, including the garbage collector, is not explicitly designed to handle memory fragmentation at the level of the underlying memory allocator.
Instead you can use Python's memory allocator (e.g., PyMalloc) often uses memory pools to manage memory allocations. Memory pools allocate memory in fixed-size blocks, which can reduce fragmentation by reducing the likelihood of creating small, non-contiguous memory chunks.
